# How to return object from user-defined Neo4j function

Tags: neo4j, user-defined-functions

I have a complicated query like this:

```
MATCH path = allShortestPaths( ... )
WITH path, reduce(x={
            specificStamp: "",
            specificCount: 0,
            ...
        },
        r IN relationships(path) |
            CASE WHEN ...
                THEN {
                    specificStamp: some-expr(x),
                    specificCount: another-expr(x),
                    ...
                }
            ...
            END
        ) AS pobj
ORDER BY pobj.specificStamp, pobj.specificCount
RETURN head(COLLECT(path)) AS path, pobj.specificStamp AS stamp, COUNT(*) AS cnt
ORDER BY length(path), stamp
```

The logic in the real code is more complex, including nested `CASE` and many complex THEN with some duplicating expressions...

To simplify the problem, it would be better to put the reduce logic into a separate function. But Neo4J user defined functions can return only a single value.

Which type of return value corresponds to this cypher expression: `{specificStamp: "", specificCount: 0}`?

May be `Object`? But according to the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.1/javadocs/org/neo4j/procedure/UserFunction.html) `Object` means `ANY` type.

May be `Map`? But which map template? `Map<String,String>` conflicts with `Map<String,Integer>`

Answer (score 0):

Return a `Map<String,Integer>` or `Map<String,Object>`

see this for valid types: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/cypher-functions/#writing-udf

Comment: What do you mean: "Map or Map"?

Comment: The markup ate the triangle brackets, should be clear now.

Answer (score 0):

`Map<String,Object>` is good enough.

Additional type conversion in the Cypher query is not required.
String field from user function comes as string. Long as long.